# Change the sidebar from left to right twentyfourteen theme

Tags: theme-development, sidebar, theme-twenty-fourteen

I am creating a site using 2014 theme. I would like to remain with the theme but however, I am interested in shifting the side bar from left to right as it is more ideal for my site. Is it possible to customise the theme in this way.

Comment: It is possible, yes, but a heck of a lot of tweaking. I just finished a theme I created from the twentyfourteen theme. I totally removed the left sidebar, and that alone was quite a job. You will need get into twentyfourteen and fight it out. Enjoy

Comment: @PieterGoosen can i have guidelines to follow. I have coding know how but am not sure i know where to go, have not coded wordpress before

Comment: @sosytee Make your own one, don't just edit TwentyFourteen. If so, then all the changes will wipe out on the next theme Update. Better make a Child theme on TwentyFourteen or edit everything to wipe out the T14 credentials to make them stay. :)

Comment: O yes, that is important like @MayeenulIslam said. Don't just edit the twenty fourteen theme. It is another case if you are creating a complete new theme using twenty fourteen as a base. In that case you will change all instances of twenty fourteen.

Comment: It is difficult to give you a guideline, as this is a lengthy process. And then there are two scenarios, one been building a new theme completely of twenty fourteen, the other, keeping twenty fouteen as a parent and creating your own child theme

Comment: You should be able to modify the CSS to float the sidebar to the right and other elements.

Comment: see also:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167886/how-do-i-customize-twenty-fourteen-with-jetpack

Answer (score 1):

Old post, yet its needed to know the solution and how-to.
Specially for `RTL` experience,

[Usefull tutorial here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-change-the-sidebar-side-in-wordpress/)

As @Mayeenul Said, [first create a child theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEYSqEBZHRE) (Video)

Then add to your `CSS file` in child theme the following:

```
.sidebar {
        float: right; // the side bar will be on right
        margin-left: -100%;
        max-width: 413px;
        position: relative;
        width: 29.4118%;
    }
.main {
        display: block;
        float: left; //the content will be on left
        margin-right: 29.4118%;
        width: 70.5882%;
    }
```

Please note that you might need to change the sidebar's and main's selector based on your working theme, ie.  `.sidebar` could be `#theme-sidebar` and `.main` could be `#theme-main`, etc.